# Angularjs $apply() for $rootscope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am working on ionic cordova platform.
At application run i am reading files which are stored on mobile.

on file success read i am storing data and binding it to $rootScope.Favorites;

But My Favorites Address are not binding:

In alert it is showing the returned data. But not updating the view

```
$cordovaFile.createDir('comMyTaxi', false).then(function(success) {
    $cordovaFile.checkFile('comMytaxi/myFavAdd.txt.gz').then(function(
        success) {
        alert('file found');
        $cordovaFile.readAsText('comMytaxi/myFavAdd.txt.gz').then(
            function(success) {
                //  alert(success);
                $rootScope.Favorites = [];
                var data = JSON.parse(success);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for (var v = 0; v < data.length; v++) {
                        $rootScope.Favorites.push(data[v]);
                    }
                    alert($rootScope.Favorites.length);
                }
            }, function(err) {
                //alert('err in reading');
            });
    }, function(err) {
        // alert('no file found');
    });
}, function(err) {
    // alert('fail file dir');
});
```

and inside view I am directly binding the $rootScope.Favorites variable

```
<div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="Address in Favorites">
                <i class="icon ion-ios7-location fontcolorMR FontSize24"></i>
                <span class="FontSize14 VerticalAlignTop">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{Address.Name}} {{Address.Street}} {{ Address.City}} {{ Address.PostCode}}</span>
                <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="removeFavorites($index)">
                    <i class="icon ion-ios7-trash FontColorB" ></i>
                </button>
            </div>
```

**How do i see changes as soon as made?**

Answer (score 0):

Since you are populating data from outside of Angular world, you just need to kick off digest loop manually once you are done:

```
if (data.length > 0) {
     for (var v = 0; v < data.length; v++) {
         $rootScope.Favorites.push(data[v]);
     }
     $rootScope.$apply();
 }
```

Comment: let me made a build i was applying $scope.$apply(); let try with $rootScope.$apply()